# Сущности сохраняются после успешного выполнения программы

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, entity-framework-core

я попробовал сделать бота для телеграмма. Для хранения данных участников группы я использую EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

И когда я закончил писать тестовое сохранение (для проверки работоспособности с базой данных), я заметил что данные не сохраняются (это было видно по дате изменения, файл базы данных не изменялся) + используя SQLite обозреватель, база данных была пуста. Но позапускав ещё немного раз, я заметил, что если завершить работу программы с кодом 0, то сохранение пройдёт. Иначе - не сохранит. У меня вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы он сохранял во время программы, а не после её завершения? Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```cs
if (message.Text!.StartsWith("/testik"))
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
         await db.Members.AddAsync(new Member { TelegramId = message.From!.Id }, cts);
         await db.SaveChangesAsync(cts);
         // Несмотря на то, что через небольшое время "SAVED" выводится на консоль, база данных сохранит сущность только после завершения программы. :<
         Console.WriteLine("SAVED");
    }
}
```

Контекст базы данных:

```cs
internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    }
}
```

Сущность:

```cs
internal class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long TelegramId { get; set; }
    public long CurrentLevel { get; set; }
    public long CurrentExperience { get; set; }
}
```

Статичный класс с конфигурацией от appsettings.json:

```cs
internal static class Configuration
{
    private static readonly IConfigurationRoot ConfigurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    internal static string Token = ConfigurationRoot["Token"]!;

    internal static string? GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationRoot.GetConnectionString(name);
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```json
{
    "Token": "Тут мой токен",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Default": "Data Source=A:\\Database\\awoxykbot.db"
    }
}
```

Comment: `(это было видно по дате изменения, файл базы данных не изменялся)` просто предположу, что у драйвера БД может быть кеш, чтобы не писать на каждый чих в файл - так как тогда операции записи в  БД будут медленные. Вам в такие подробности в 99% случаев нет резона лазать.

Comment: попробуйте начать с описания проблемы, у вас на работает что то или что? Ну скинет система изменения чуть позже, что с того то?

Comment: @tym32167, сделал ещё немного проверок и вы оказались правы. Хоть данные не в базу данных сохранились, но всё же сохранились, и я смог обратиться к этим данным.

Comment: Sqlite, как и любая другая РСУБД не хранит изменения в оперативной памяти - это слишком ненадёжно. Дело, наверняка, в [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). Другие приложения не видят эти изменения, потому что sqlite принципиально одноклиентская СУБД.

Comment: На что ещё следует обратить внимание: [Disk drives that do not honor sync requests](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_disk_drives_that_do_not_honor_sync_requests) - некоторые накопители (несерверные) ложно рапортуют, что запись завершена, хотя ещё держат данные в своём аппаратном кэше. / И вот ещё: [Memory-Mapped I/O](https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html) - но по умолчанию оно выключено.

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, вопрос решён.

Во время запуска программы, используя `Entity Framework Core`, он не добавляет напрямую в базу данных, а добавляет в кеш-файлы, которые находятся в том же каталоге, что и сам файл базы данных. Вот что получилось в телеграмме:

```
я: /mystat
бот: такого пользователя нет
я: /testik
бот: Вы успешно добавлены в базу данных!
я: /testik
бот: Данный пользователь уже в базе данных.
я: /mystat
бот: *мой телеграмм айди*
```